# Padre: how to view/examine Perl's special variables?

Tags: perl, debugging, padre

Sorry if this is a newbie question. I can't seem to find a response for this question:

In Padre, how do I view/examine the values of Perl "special variables" (like $_, or $/, for example?)

It seems that the "view" button lists a variable's value only if you highlight that variable in the editor. But Perl's special variables are not part of the explicit program code.

TIA - Helen

Comment: This question has been answered on perlmonks http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=953069

Comment: At this time (13:35 EST, 18:35 GMT) the question has not been answered @ PerlMonks

Comment: The answer on Perlmonks is to upgrade Padre then follow the answer to "Show Debugger". You said that you were using 0.86. The version on CPAN is 0.94.

Comment: @briandfoy: I am using ActivePerl on Windows. The latest padre version compatible with that is 0.86.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried highlighting them in the parts that matter to your code? The thing is that the special vars change all the time depending on the context so it'll be hard to understand what they mean.

Example:

```
sub Something
{
$_; <<< highlight this
@_; <<<< or this
#do something
$value = shift;

}
```

Comment: I can't highlight them since they do not appear in the program text. "The thing is that the special vars change all the time" - that's no problem, since if you go step by step, what's interesting is the value of the special variable (e.g. $_) at that specific point.

Comment: What i meant is that you should try write them where you need to see them and highlight them. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I'll try that and report. But what your'e saying is that there is no way to view the special variables in the debugger, except if you show them in the code?

Comment: What happens if you highlight them at the beginning of the script? Do they dissapear when the scope changes?

Comment: It's working. Good workaround (it's a workaround, in my opinion), since an elegant functionality should have provided a way to view the special variables in the debugger, without the need to explicitly enter them  and edit and modify the program code.

Comment: Ok, i'm glad, ask the Padre developers for the feature.